# PGP files included on email

Tags: pgp

I just got an email from a professor that included two files, with no clues about them in the message. The files are named OpenPGP_...EA.asc and OpenPGP_signature. I figured, since I asked some stuff about cryptography that he may be sending some hidden message there, but after some "research" on google I'm guessing that it's just his personal public key and his signature (?) perhaps. I'm just not sure why he included those files, so any hint about it would be nice.

Thanks!

Comment: You could ask him about it. Most likely, he just does that for every email

Comment: Is it really .ass not .asc? The latter is a convention for the 'ASCII-armored' format often used in PGP.